# Flask hello.py basic app not running?

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

when I enter python hello.py in the command line, I get another bash prompt. I'm not sure what could be the problem since I'm able to run a virtualenv and when I check which version of flask I have the latest version, `>>> '0.10.1'` installed.

```
Opals-MacBook-Pro:~ opalkale$ cd myproject
Opals-MacBook-Pro:myproject opalkale$ ls
hello.py    venv
Opals-MacBook-Pro:myproject opalkale$ . venv/bin/activate
(venv)Opals-MacBook-Pro:myproject opalkale$ python hello.py
(venv)Opals-MacBook-Pro:myproject opalkale$
```

The code for hello.py looks like:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

    if __name__ == "__main__":
            app.run()
```

This code was taken from: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#quickstart

Comment: Did you include the `if __name__ == '__main__':` portion of the script?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `hello.py` rather than a link to the Flask documentation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your file does not match the example in the documentation. You've placed the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block inside the definition of `hello()`.

Whitespace is significant in Python. It needs to be placed outside the function definition (i.e., aligned all the way to the left). Doing so will execute the `if` when the script is run. The way it exists now, you would need to import the `hello` module and call the `hello` function. That isn't what you want. Fix the indentation and you will be all set.

Comment: I should have taken a closer look at the code instead of trying to reinstall flask and virtualenv a bunch of times thank you! It's working perfect now.

Answer (score 1):

If the server already works and when you back after a while you get this error: `flask command not defined`.

First run this command:

```sh
pip list
```

... if flask is not there reinstall it again.

1. Run this command:

```sh
# In mac
venv/bin/activate
# or Windows
venv/Scripts/activate
```

2. Install Flask running:

```sh
pip install Flask
```

3. Set environment variable

```sh
export FLASK_APP=yourServerName
```

4. Run flask back agan

```sh
flask run
```

Answer (score 0):

Python always is a headache with these spaces. I use sublime text editor that helps me to figure out these spacing syntax issues really quick.

In your case, just move if **name** == "**main**": to the left, so that that if is out of the function return above.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You must take care of **Indentation**. Tab and four blank spaces are different in it. Go with four blank spaces.
You can re-create like below.
I'm providing custom port also.

```
    from flask import Flask
    app = Flask(__name__)


    @app.route("/")
    def hello():
        return "Hello World!"


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```